# What's the differnece between service principals and user principals?

Tags: apache-kafka, kerberos, mit-kerberos

I'm setting up a Kafka-cluster with kerberos, and the instructions/documentation is a little sparse when it comes to multi-node clusters (specifically the service principals.

What's the differnece between service principals and user principals (apart from the fqdn component and preauth). What advantages/disadvanges will there be if i tried to run kafka brokers with user keytabs rather than service keytabs.

Comment: In a strictly kerberos-sense a user principal and service principal only differ by name format. A user has a form of `user@realm` and service principal has a form of `service/principal@realm`. A client running as a user principal will get a ticket on behalf of that user targeting a service principal. So your kafka cluster is a service principal when receiving tickets to authenticate users.

Comment: I believe Hortonworks and Cloudera have documentation on this. They have an automated process to set it up, though